# Browser not displaying image, but Fiddler has the data

Tags: html, iis, fiddler

I'm generating a chart image png file on-the-fly on our accounting website. IIS web server. Usually it works, but intermittently it doesn't display, just displays the broken image link. (Confirmed it happens in IE 9 and Chrome browsers at minimum.) The problem occurs most often on local dev servers, often on test servers, and less often on the powerful production server farm.

Refreshing the page often fixes the display problem. When it fails it usually happens very quickly, not after a timeout delay. Loading the image takes longer than the failing path.

I've reproduced the problem with fiddler attached, and fiddler shows the image data gets to the client and displays the image just fine in ImageView. Fiddler has the image, the browser does not.

I'm out of ideas after proving it gets to the client browser. Any suggestions of things that could be wrong? Any "right" words I should be using to describe this problem in a search?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in any of the browsers consoles?

Comment: Reran the repro to confirm, no errors in the IE browser console when the image fails.

Comment: What are the response headers on the HTTP response? Are you trying to use JavaScript to load the image or is it a plain `<IMG>` tag?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Cache-Control: private
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Content-Type: image/png
    Expires: Mon, 16 Sep 2013 16:32:14 GMT
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Mon, 16 Sep 2013 16:32:14 GMT

Comment: Standard IMG tag, no javascript involved. Only oddness is the httphandler on the server that draws the chart associated with the id.'http://localhost/X/Restricted/Charts/434.200/chart.png?li=75733-1540-75578&lv=0&lk=0&cid=55f0969b-a567-492c-819f-d7c7085ba4c5&h=1&l=1'

Comment: It's a little odd that the image is configured to expire immediately, but that *shouldn't* matter. In Fiddler, if you click `Transformer` and untick the `Chunked transfer encoding` checkbox, is there any error message? If you then go to the `ImageView` tab, is the image rendered as expected?